# Django-Filter between two dates

Tags: django, django-filter

Unfortunately I'm stuck and can't find a working solution yet, my Model looks like this:

```
class SubOperatorAssignment(models.Model):
    operator = models.ForeignKey(Operator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_operator = models.ForeignKey(SubOperator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='End Date')
```

And I would like to let the User select a Date (with the Django-Filter Library) and check in the Filter if the given Date is between the Models Start and End Date. Unfortunately Date Filter only accepts one field name and there seems to be no lookop_expr for between. Thankful for any hints on how to achieve this!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SubOperatorAssignment.objects.filter(start_date__gte=date, end_date__lte=date)
```

Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but at least a starting point:

```
class SubOperatorAssignmentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    operator = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Operator.objects.all(), label='Operator')

    sub_operator = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name='sub_operator', queryset=SubOperator.objects.all(),
                                                    label='Sub Operator')

    test = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='test',
                                     method='filter_between_date_range',
                                     )

    class Meta:
        model = SubOperatorAssignment
        fields = {}

    def filter_between_date_range(self, queryset, name, value):
        _model = self.Meta.model
        ret_qset = _model.objects.filter(start_date__lte=value, end_date__gte=value)

        return ret_qset
```

Implement a custom filter method and use a CharFilter which actually accepts a method parameter.

The only downside is that it be would nice to move this function outside of the class (since I would like to use it in multiple filters)